# Scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I want a scatterplot in R for points (x,y). 
where 500 sample points of x,y are drawn from Normal distribution N(0,1) and N(0,16). Also mark these points as red from distribution N(0,1) and blue for N(0,16).

I am new to R and know only basic plotting. Anyone please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, read the excellent manuals, especially Section 12.1 of Introduction to R: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#High_002dlevel-plotting-commands

Comment: If X is N(0,1) and Y is N(0, 16) can you tell us where the color information comes from?

Comment: Is something like this that you are looking for?         plot(rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=16),col='blue')
points(rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=1),col='red')

Comment: As hinted by DWin, the plot you want is impossible.  Each point is defined by an x, and y value, which is also your two distributions.  You're saying the points will be different colours based on which distribution they come from but each point is defined by both of them.

Comment: @Andres: your code is two lines but as a comment would work better with a semi-colon as in `plot(rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=16),col='blue');points(rnorm(500,mean=0,sd=1),col='red')`

Answer (score 4):

As the comments suggest, you have two possibilities with data from

```
x <- rnorm(500, mean=0, sd=sqrt(1))
y <- rnorm(500, mean=0, sd=sqrt(16))
```

One way would be to plot y against x, but your colour suggestions do not mean anything

```
plot(y ~ x)
```

Alternatively you can show the two sets of data with colours, remembering that y probably has a wider range than x.

```
plot(y, col="blue")
points(x, col="red")
```

The plots you get are

[image]